# Why is this python script slowly chewing up my RAM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymongo

This script slowly eats my RAM.  When I run it, I can see the RAM usage of Python creep up by approx 1mb with each loop, but I can't figure out why.  I have figured out that it is the iteration of the query that adds the RAM, but that's all I can figure out.  Any help would be awesome.

```
from haystack.pmod import piliPlacement #this is the SA model
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


now = datetime.now()


engine = create_engine('mssql://xxxxxxx;uid=user;pwd=xxxxx',echo=False)


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


def syncPlacements(session):
    query = session.query(piliPlacement).filter(piliPlacement.Time > now)
    pili_placements = [p.ID_Placement for p in query.all()] # this is what adds the RAM
    del pili_placements
    print 'loop'


while True:
    session = Session()
    syncPlacements(session)
    sleep(3)
```

Comment: There is a clear bug in this code that is (probably) unrelated.  You are checking `if countPiliPlacements != countHaystackPlacements():` ... note that the first part is a function, not a function call.

Comment: And checking the number of items in each database is not a robust means of synchronisation ... if someone both removes and adds an item to one database within your three seconds you won't detect it.

Comment: Donkopotamus, guilty on both counts.  I just discovered the function thing too.. oops!  And you're right, I should be reconciling ID's.

Comment: @Donkapotamus, I have simplified the code sample.  Can you take another look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After stripping it right back, and chatting to a guy on the SA IRC channel, it appeared to be a Mac OSX only problem.  So I set it up on Linux but the same thing occured.  In the end, I resorted to running the script on a crontab.  Works fine now.

M

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see if **mdb** is slowly getting larger as it does more work. That is why I'd assume that this would be occuring. It is the only object that doesn't look like it would be garbage collected in your example, and it also happens to be an object. So, I would definitely look into what it's doing as it is used more and more.

I'd wonder if it's maintaining a list of queries that have executed.

Comment: I pulled out all the *mdb* stuff and it still kept climbing, so I think I must be mishandling the SA session.  Thanks monokrome

Answer (score 0):

Just 3 questions

Where does `session` come from?

Why not put `mdb = Connection().haystack` into the `while True` loop (and btw `session.close()` too)? And pass `mdb` and `session` to `syncPlacements`?

Whole code block is copied just with just two differences (i.e. calculate matches, save or remove)?

Comment: 1.  `session` comes from haystack.pmod which is the SA model and engine setup.  2. Good point   3.  another good point.  I'm going to do a re-write and see what happens with the memory issue.

Comment: I have simplified the code sample. Can you take another look?